# React native re-render causes view to scroll to top - Do my keys change between renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, render

I am using react native, redux and flatlist. I render 10 items and then fetch / render the next 10 items on click (load more). My problem is that when I use setState(to increase the page counter) (thats why I dont use setstate in my code) to fetch more items (i use pagination) or ask whether or not Im fetching (true when fetching -> shown loading sign, false when fetched -> showing items), that triggers
a re-render and my view gets scrolled to top.

Ive been reading for a while now and event.preventDefault (as sometimes suggested) doesnt work and I do believe that my problem is the key / parent tree of the corresponding element changes between renders. I do give each item the key of its ID which is always unique. Am I doing it wrong? Or what else could be causing this? Thanks!

```
class App extends React.Component {  
    state = {
        page : 0
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData(0)
        this.state.page++;
    }        
    load = () => {
        this.props.fetchData(this.state.page);
        this.state.page++;
    }    
    renderRow = ({item}) => {
        return (
            <Item
                key={item.id}
                coin={item}
            />
        )
    }
    renderButton() {
        return <Button
            title="Load more"
            onPress={this.load}
        />
    }    
    render() {
        if (this.props.isFetching) {
            return (
                <View>
                  <Text>Loading</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    style={{width: '100%'}}
                    data={this.props.data}
                    renderItem={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                    ListFooterComponent={this.renderButton.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }    
}    
mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isFetching: state.data.isFetching,
        data: state.data.data    
    }
}    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchData})(App)
```

Comment: 2 things to fix. 1) Don't mutate state directly. Use setState. 2) Use keyExtractor property from FlatList. Don't add keys manually.

Comment: using keyExtractor  doesnt help either and why I mutate the state directly without using setState is because when I setstate, the re-render makes the view to scroll to top. Thats my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey change your render method return like below :

```
return (
          { this.state.isFetching && <View> <Text>Loading</Text> </View>}

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    style={{width: '100%'}}
                    data={this.props.data}
                    renderItem={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                    ListFooterComponent={this.renderButton.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
```